# Gouvêa: proof of the p-adic Weierstrass Preparation Theorem

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I am working through Gouvêa's "Introduction to p-adic Numbers". Now I am stuck at Theorem 7.2.6. (p-adic Weierstrass Preparation Theorem). He says that the proof is similar to Proposition 7.2.3. My problem is that the conclusions of these theorems are similar but not the same. For example in the proportion he concludes that for a polynomial $f$ and a polynomial $g$ we have $\lVert g(X)\rVert_1=\lVert f(X)\rVert_1$. But in the theorem he concludes that for a power series $f$ and a polynomial $g$ we have $\lVert f(X)-g(X)\rVert_1<1$. Or in the theorem he claims that we can choose the power series $h$ to start with the term $1$. Where does he get these additional properties about $g$ and $h$ from?

Comment: I’d love to help you on this, but my old edition of Gouvêa ends at ch. 6. I do know lots about WPrep, though. Maybe if you send scans of the appropriate pages, I can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Where may I send it to you?

Comment: You can click on my blue name and see the Brown eddress.

Comment: I tried to send you an email but both addresses (the one written out and the actual linked address) didn‘t work.

Comment: Strange indeed. Try jonathandlubin@gmail.com